# When using FTP, can only connect to server as root user, not users I have created

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, ftp, filezilla

I have a server set up on a DreamCompute. I am attempting to connect to my server through FTP, and have VSFTPD installed.

Strangely, I am able to log in as the root user (with no password) through the FTP Client FileZilla, but not a sudo user I created for the purpose of managing media on the site.

Extra strangely, when logged in as the root user on FileZilla I am able to upload (having configured VSFTPD) media to anywhere on the site...except the folders of another user, where my site lives.

FileZilla returns an unhelpful "could not connect to server".

Any guidance you all could offer would be much appreciated!

Things I've tried:

Changing pam_service_name to "ftp", "sftp", and "vsftpd"

Turning PasswordAuthentication on in etc/ssh/sshd_config

Edit 1: I am attempting to connect via sftp://

Comment: AFAIK `vsftpd` is an FTP server. I'm sure `sshd_config` belongs to the SSH server, which is also relevant for SFTP. The most important thing: *FTP is not SFTP*. Can you tell which protocol you're using (or trying to use) when FileZilla works (doesn't work, respectively)?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/544850/create-new-vsftpd-user-and-lock-to-specify-home-login-directory

Comment: "I am attempting to connect via `sftp://`" – So you're not connecting to `vsftpd` using FTP. If to anything, you're connecting to `sshd` using SFTP. If you want to use FTP then specify `ftp://` in the address. What happens now?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Previously I would get an error that the server wanted SFTP only. Now, after my tinkering (I've set pam_service_name back to "vsftpd"), I don't get any error at all from Filezilla, just a timeout.

Comment: Any detail that clarifies the question should be in the question, not in comments. There is no need to indicate added parts (like your "Edit 1"), we have the [revision history](https://superuser.com/posts/1716725/revisions) for this.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out my particular issue. I hadn't set "password_authentication" in sshd_confg to "yes." Once I did, that did the trick.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I keep telling you you're confusing FTP and SFTP. `sshd_confg` affects SFTP (and more). It has nothing to do with FTP and `vsftpd` the question is about. It's good you found a setup that satisfies you. In general it's good to share solutions, nevertheless it's wrong to spread *misconceptions*. Since the question is about FTP and `vsftpd`, the answer about SFTP and `sshd` is a *workaround* at best. Different protocols, different daemons, separate configs. Analogy: a car that doesn't start cannot be fixed by riding a motorbike. The motorbike will get you there, but the car is still broken down.